# How can I set images ti collection elements?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, collections, uicollectionview

I crete collection and I want set images to it elements. Now I can set just background color.

My code:

pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource Methods

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(AFIndexedCollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
NSArray *collectionViewArray = self.colorArray[collectionView.index];
return collectionViewArray.count;
}


-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(AFIndexedCollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CollectionViewCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSArray *collectionViewArray = self.colorArray[collectionView.index];
cell.backgroundColor = collectionViewArray[indexPath.item];

return cell;
}
```

AFTableViewCell

```
 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
 {
if (!(self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) return nil;

UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 9, 10);
layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(44, 44);
layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
self.collectionView = [[AFIndexedCollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:layout];
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CollectionViewCellIdentifier];
self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
[self.contentView addSubview:self.collectionView];
```

return self;
}

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
[super layoutSubviews];

self.collectionView.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
}

-(void)setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate:(id<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>)dataSourceDelegate index:(NSInteger)index
{
self.collectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate;
self.collectionView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate;
self.collectionView.index = index;

[self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Good luck with that :)  Actually, what you need to do is add a `UIImageView` to the cell's `contentView`.

Comment: @user3386109, yep, but I have '-[AFTableViewCell setImageView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8cd4c30'

Comment: self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    self.imageView.frame = self.collectionView.frame;
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.imageView];